# mxnet ndarray indexing in python

Tags: python, mxnet

I am new to mxnet. I just installed mxnet 1.0.0 and python 3.5 on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine with CUDA 8.0 and cudnn 7.0.5.

My code is given below. I am trying to store image data in an ndarray. (see https://github.com/ypwhs/DogBreed_gluon/blob/master/get_features_v3.ipynb for the original code)
 -

```
X_224 = nd.zeros((n, 3, 224, 224))
X_299 = nd.zeros((n, 3, 299, 299))

mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
std = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])

for i, (fname, breed) in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=n):
    img = cv2.imread('data/train/%s.jpg' % fname)
    img_224 = ((cv2.resize(img, (224, 224))[:, :, ::-1] / 255.0 - mean) / std).transpose((2, 0, 1))
    img_299 = ((cv2.resize(img, (299, 299))[:, :, ::-1] / 255.0 - mean) / std).transpose((2, 0, 1))

    X_224[i] = nd.array(img_224) <-- I get error in this line
    X_299[i] = nd.array(img_299)
```

Here is the error I get:

> ValueError: Indexing NDArray with index=0 and type=class 'numpy.int64' is not supported.

I am assuming it has to with indexing a multi dimensional nd array. So I tried slicing `- X_224[i:i+1] = ....` but that gave me another error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the type of the index from `numpy.int64` to `int`; e.g. `i = int(i)` before trying to set the slice.

`df.iterrows()` returns tuples, where the type of the first element depends on the type of the dataframe index. `df.iterrows()` returned tuples of types (`int`,`pandas.core.series.Series`) when running the Github example, so no conversion was necessary for me (using Pandas 0.22).

Aside from this specific issue, you might want to take a look at Gluon Datasets and DataLoaders for this task. `mxnet.gluon.data.vision.datasets.ImageFolderDataset` can be used for loading images, and it accepts an image transformation function through the `transform` argument.

```
def transform_fn(data, label):
    mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406])
    std = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    data = ((cv2.resize(data, (224, 224))[:, :, ::-1] / 255.0 - mean) / std).transpose((2, 0, 1))
    return data, label

image_directory = os.path.join(data_dir, "train")
dataset = mx.gluon.data.vision.ImageFolderDataset(image_directory, transform=transform_fn)
data_loader = mx.gluon.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)

for data, label in data_loader:
    ...
```